# Let G be a group and A and B be normal subgroups of G such that A is isomorphic to B. Show by an example that G/A is NOT isomorphic G/B.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

I let G = $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ and let $A = 2\mathbb{Z}$ and $B = 3\mathbb{Z}$...which I thought would work.

I can show these are are normal subgroups and that they are isomorphic easily.

However, I am having trouble showing that $G/2\mathbb{Z}$ is not isomorphic to $G/3\mathbb{Z}$.

Help is appreciated! If there is a better G, A, B to use here, suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ has order $n$.

Comment: I think the property of G/A isomorphic to G/B when A isomorphic to B is true only if G is finite. (I think it is due Langrage Theorem for subgroups).

Comment: @Novice, it's not necessarily true for finite groups either. Take $G$ to be the direct product of a cyclic group of order $4$ and a cyclic group of order $2$. It has 3 subgroups of order $2$ (all normal, since the group is abelian), and two of the quotients are cyclic (of order $4$) while the last one is isomorphic to the Klein group.

Comment: @verret hey thanks.

Answer (score 3):

An isomorphism is a bijection, however $|G/A|=2$ and $|G/B|=3$.

Comment: How do I prove that? I know that I can find the order of finite quotient groups using Lagrange's theorem but I'm not sure how to handle infinite groups?

Comment: @Minerva you can use the first isomorphism theorem, you know $\Bbb Z\mapsto\Bbb Z/n$ given by reducing mod $n$ is surjective.